# Passing a private method of the class as the compare operator for std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I am writing a code to solve the following problem: Given a set of numbers `x[0]`, `x[1]`, ..., `x[N-1]`, find the permutation that makes them sorted in the ascending order. In the other words, I would like to find a permutation on {0,2,...,N-1} such as `i[0]`, `i[1]`, ..., `i[N-1]` such that `x[i[0]] <= x[i[1]] <= ... <= x[i[N-1]]`.

For this, I have stored the `x` vector and an index vector `i` (initially filled with `i[j] = j`) as private members of a class. I have also defined a private method as

```
bool MyClass::compare(size_t s, size_t t) {
    return (x[s] < x[t]);
}
```

Now, I would call the `std::sort` as follows

```
std::sort(i.begin(), i.end(), compare);
```

and I expect to get the desired result. But the code does not compile and I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<long unsigned int>::iterator, std::vector<long unsigned int>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

I must have done everything correctly as also the documentation of `std::sort` mentions that I can pass a function as the compare operator to `std::sort` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Thanks for all the helps in advance.

Comment: cplusplus.com is *not* "the documentation". That would be the C++ standard.

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of issues with your approach. The first one and most evident is that you cannot use a member function as a free function. To be able to call `compare` you need an object of type `MyClass` and two integers. Inside `std::sort` the implementation is going to try to call a *free* (non-member) function with only two integer arguments.

Other than that, you cannot create a pointer to a member function without explicitly taking its address. The line `std::sort(..., compare);` will not compile for a member function. While non-member functions will automatically decay to a pointer to the function that is not the case here.

In C++11 there are two different solutions that you can take. The most generic is creating a lambda that captures the `this` argument:

```
std::sort(std::begin(i),std::end(i),
          [](int x, int y) { return compare(x,y); }); // or maybe even implement here
```

A different approach would be binding the object and the member function into a functor:

```
std::sort(std::begin(i),std::end(i),
          std::bind(&MyClass::compare,this,_1,_2));
```

In this last case, the `std::bind` function will create an object that implements `operator()` taking two arguments and will call the member function `MyClass::compare` on the object pointed by `this`.

The semantics of both approaches are slightly different, but in this case you can use either one.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed info. So, both of the approaches only work on C++11 as you mentioned. Is there any way to do it such that the code can be compiled also with the older versions of C++ compiler? (I guess the second one should be doable if I use `boost::bind` instead of `std::bind`)

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi: Yes, `boost::bind` is an alternative to the second. If you have a single use of this, and you really need to make it work without C++11 or `boost::bind` you could write a small functor that stores a pointer to the object, takes the two arguments and dispatches to the appropriate function (manual implementation of the lambda).

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind instance methods have an implicit first parameter - the `this` pointer of the object. Thus your comparison operator is not of the type expected by `std::sort` - it takes three arguments instead of the expected 2. Use a `bind` function to get around this(for instance `boost::bind`). Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304203/812912) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the implicit `this` pointer is the first argument or the last? Also isn't it possible to use `std::bind` instead of `boost::bind`?

Comment: Yes it is possible - that is why I said **a** bind function. And the this **pointer** is implicit first argument for instance methods.

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi: Note that whether the `this` pointer is the first or last (or anywhere in between) is implementation defined [although all implementations I know make it the first] and quite unimportant given that you cannot just call the member function passing a pointer in the appropriate location. Other than unrolling your own assembly code, the order of arguments is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

One way round this problem is to define a function call operator in your class ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605400/c-stdsort-with-predicate-function-in-class)):

```
bool MyClass::operator() (size_t s, size_t t) {
    return (x[s] < x[t]);
}
```

Then you can invoke sort() method like this:

```
sort(i.begin(), i.end(), *this);
```

Comment: This can be quite expensive, the comparator is passed by value.

Comment: While this will make it compile, it involves creating (at least one) copy of `*this`, which might be expensive. If this approach was to be taken in C++11, you could pass `std::ref(*this)` instead of `*this` to get cheaper copies (In C++03 you can use boost for this also)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to comment that the answer of @dribeas didn't work for me. I'm using the lambda function, and I had to edit it:

```
 std::sort(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(),
      [this](int x, int y) { return compare(x,y); });
```