# Accessing member from a static function - std::foreach

Tags: c++, oop, static-members

Is it possible to access a static member function through `std::for_each`?

I've hit a problem with a class I'm trying to code. I have a class `Foo` which in the member section initialises an object of `Boo` and I need to access this inside of a static member function that is used in `std::foreach()` details below:

Foo.h

```
class Foo {
   public: 
      Foo() {

          w = getInstanceOfAnotherClass(0, 0); // this works fine!
      }
      void Transform();

      static inline void processBlock(std::vector<double> &vect);

   private: 
     std::vector<std::vector<double> > data;
     Boo* w;
};
```

Here is the problem: Inside of the member function `Transform` I have the following:

```
void Foo::Transform() 
{
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), processBlock);
}
```

And in `ProcessBlock` I have the following:

```
void Foo::processBlock(std::vector<double> &vect) 
{
    std::vector<double> vars = w.getDataBack<double>(); 
}
```

The error that is returned is that `w` invalid use of member 'w' in static member function, now, I know what the problem is.. But I don't know know of a workaround. I decided to create another function that wasn't static and then call this function from inside of `processBlock`, however, the member function cannot be called without declaring an object, which, would therefore re-set the value of `w` and this is not what I want.

I hope someone can help and this post isn't confusing.

Comment: Can you use C++11? If so, the easiest solution is to write a lambda that captures `this` instead of a static function.

Comment: @jrok Hey thank you for the reply. I can use C++11 but, I'm new to the new standards and Lambda, could you recommend a place to research this, or, provide an example? Thank you

Comment: since `w` is a pointer, you also should write `w->`

Comment: I think a very similar question was asked just today. Let me try to find it. EDIT: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273997/passing-a-private-method-of-the-class-as-the-compare-operator-for-stdsort/18274208#18274208).

Comment: Couldn't you call 'processBlock' with a pointer to `this` as a parameter?

Comment: @Phorce: The lambda would look like `[this](std::vector<double> &vect){processBlock(vect);}` If you wait a year, you should be able to change the parameter type to `auto&` when C++14 introduces polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: @JoeMajsterski: No, because `for_each` calls its function with a single argument. If you added a second parameter to the static function, you'd need a lambda or `bind` just as you would with a non-static function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FooThe way I'd do it is with a function call instead of a static function. Use

`void processBlock(std::vector<double> &vect);`

And

`std::for_each(data.begin(),data.end(),std::bind(&Foo::processBlock,this,_1))`

Comment: This works :) I really want to try to Lambda approach tho, but, this works great!

Comment: Lamda's work fine, I'm just more used to bind because visual studio 10 :-P. It should just be `[this](std::vector<double>& vect){this->processBlock(vect);}` but I'm honestly not all that familiar with it, and I can't test it now and don't like posting things I can't test.